"You can't use macro parameter character" error (bibliography)
Im getting a "You can't use macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode" error when creating a citation. The bibliographic entry contains a link to a website that contains the #symbol. I've tried#` and setting that part of the website in math mode, but both don't seem to solve the problem. Is there a way to reference the bibliographic entry with that symbol?
Here's the bibliographic entry in question:
@unpublished{Luna,
    author = {Logos Biosystems},
    title = {Luna-II TM Automated Cell Counter},
    note = {Retrieved from https://logosbio.com/luna-ll/#03 in October 2024}
}


In this case load the url (or xurl) package and wrap the URL with the \url{...}  command.

If you're using biblatex (and maybe also in other bib systems) you can also use the url and urldate fields and let the used style decide how to format that information.


The main recommendation is to (a) load the xurl (or url) package and (b) encase the full URL string in a \url{...} directive. The note field should look like this:
note   = {Retrieved from \url{https://logosbio.com/luna-ll/#03} in October 2024},

This change assures that TeX-special characters, such as #, don't get misinterpreted.

In addition, you should change the author field to
author = {{Logos Biosystems}},

i.e., encase the field in an additional pair of curly braces. This informs BibTeX that it's not dealing with a person with given name "Logos" and surname "Biosystems" but, rather, with a corporate author. Making this change is important as it assures, at a minimum, that the entry will be sorted under "L" for Logos instead of under "B" for Biosystems.

Separately, I would also change the "TM" string in the title field to \texttrademark. That, or just omit "TM" entirely.



A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%% Create a sample bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@unpublished{Luna,
    author = {{Logos Biosystems}},
    title  = {{Luna-II\texttrademark{} Automated Cell Counter}},
    note   = {Retrieved from \url{https://logosbio.com/luna-ll/#03} in October 2024}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % or some other suitable citation management package
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bibliography style

\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks at arbitrary locations in URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}

